# How can I add solid collideable borders to the viewport regardless of the resolution?

Tags: unity, c#, android, physics, viewport

I'm making a game in Unity. In my game I have a sphere, what I need is for the sphere to rebound against the edges of the viewport.

For that I used a few Gameobjects with 2D box colliders.

The problem is that when game resolution changes, the edges of the camera are extended or reduced, and empty gameobjects are not on the edge.

How can I make gameobjects which always stay on the edge of the viewport?

Is this the correct way to make it bounce at the edges?

Answer (score 1):

There's more than just one way to achieve this. In my case, if this was a core mechanic, I would avoid using the colliders and just use my own code for detecting when the ball has hit an edge and then send it back with a mirrored vector. Your method is not wrong, it just wouldn't be my choice because of the lack of control. Anyway, here's how to do what you're trying to do:

Create a screen-space canvas. Put a canvas scaler script on it and set it to scale with screen size. Make your boundary gameobjects into children of that canvas. Then align the borders with the canvas' borders and it will scale to any resolution you want.

These are my working values as of the time of the tests:

[image]

The method I used here will use a script to decide the BoxCollider2D's size, but you can manually type the values in.

Here's the script for the child object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RectBoxSize : MonoBehaviour {
    public RectTransform objectRect, parentCanvas;
    public BoxCollider2D boxCollider;
    Rect canvasOld;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        if (parentCanvas == null)
        {
            parentCanvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>().GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        }
            canvasOld = parentCanvas.rect;
        if (boxCollider == null)
        {
            boxCollider = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
        }
        if (objectRect == null)
        {
            objectRect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        }
        boxCollider.size = objectRect.rect.size;
        boxCollider.offset = new Vector2(0, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(canvasOld.width != parentCanvas.rect.width
            || canvasOld.height != parentCanvas.rect.height)
        {
            boxCollider.size = objectRect.rect.size;
            boxCollider.offset = new Vector2(0, 0);
            canvasOld = parentCanvas.rect;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a gif that shows how the code works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the problem continues, because the game is in position 0, 0, 0, but the canvas is in another position.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the RectTransform's Anchors?

[image]

With this you can "snap" objects inside the canvas and it will follow the position on any resolutions.